# PHP - Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: php, variables

I have a php file:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
function test(){ 
    echo $a;
} 
test();
?>
```

And I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: a in X:\...\test.php on line 4
```

Using XAMPP @ 32bit W7.

Comment: Its because of the function scope. you would need to write global $a; at the top of the function, but you should avoid global variables. Read a bit about scope in php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: PHP does not have real global variables. You need to chain to the shared scope if you want this to work. (Example too abstract. But it's frequently misused by newcomers; function parameters are usually the advisable approach.)

Comment: Also NARQ: Please formulate your posts as actual questions. Add more details and real code if you want case-specific help. See [higher quality question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and [sample code](http://sscce.org/) howtos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variables have function scope. `$a` inside the function is not the same as `$a` outside the function. Inside the function you have not defined a variable `$a`, so it doesn't exist. Pass it into the function:

```
$a = 1;
function test($a) { 
    echo $a;
} 
test($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have trouble understanding *variable scope*. `$a` is defined in the *global* scope, but not in the *function* scope. If you want your function to know what `$a` contains, you have two choices :

1. Make it global (usually a bad solution)
2. Add a new argument to your function, and pass your variable to your function

Answer (score 1):

You can use global as advised, but that is bad practice.  If you need variables in a function from outside the function then pass them as parameters.

```
$a = 1;
function test($a) {
    echo $a;
}
test($a);
```